# Sharepoint Productivity Hub Slider

Tags: 2010, productivity

I have just installed the Sharepoint Productivity hub. I will not be using when implementing my own Sharepoint system, but am using it for guidance during the development. 
On the Productivity hub main page there is a slider which cycles through the software they have provided documentation for, my question is: Does anyone know how this was included? I really like the idea and was hoping to insert something similar into my site. I'm afraid my reputation on here is not high enough to post a picture (I guess they dont really like me...) but if you dont know what I'm talking about you probably havent seen the productivity hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the slider - the Silverlight Product Carousel - can be found here, http://productivityhub.codeplex.com/.